# How to find out how to interract with a smart contract on NEAR? Where to see its source or byte code?

Tags: nearprotocol

Having checked 2 main NEAR explorers, the  official one and **nearscan**, I haven't found neither any way to see the byte code and source code of smart contracts on them, nor ability to interract with a smart contract, nor check what functions a smart contract has. On any Ethereum Explorer, and on a few others, all of this is possible.

Or perhaps I've missed something?

Is it correct that on NEAR explorers neither of the abovementioned features exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very good question.

You can use "Stats Gallery", this tool let you see Stats from an account (Or contract - which is an account with a contract deployed).

But let you interact with the Contract too.

https://stats.gallery/mainnet/nit.globaledu.near/contract?t=week

This is an example, you can see the functions of my "Feedback Contract".
Instead of this you can add a Testnet contract and try to call some functions, maybe the next one:

https://stats.gallery/testnet/alpha.neatar.testnet/contract?t=week

And the source code of the tool is here, just in case you want to know exactly how is does:

https://github.com/NEARFoundation/stats.gallery/blob/90c76d452bdb8ce12a7b1a4675df453f437494cc/src/composables/contract/useContract.ts

Saludos